# How to Skip a Portion of the ”Code” in the source code while doing GoogleTest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, googletest, googlemock

I tried using a debug flag addition (**GOOGLE_TEST**) in the source code and defined it in the TEST/Makefile.am. but the things didn’t work. I am using C++ Language.
Note: I don’t want to change anything in the SRC Directory code which will affect the production code and its Makefile.am

## Test Class in SRC Directory

```
class Common: public Thread {
 public:
  friend class test_common;
  Common {
  }
  ~Common () {
  }
  virtual void ThreadMain();
 protected:
  virtual void ProcessData(void);
};
void Common::ProcessData(void) {
  #ifndef __GOOGLE_TEST__
  while (1) { }
  #endif
}
```

## TESTCODE in test Directory

```
class test_common : public ::testing::Test {
};
TEST_F(test_common, create_common) {
    Common commonObj();
    commonObj. ProcessData ();
}
```

## OUTPUT

GTest Stuck in the While loop part even after defining the flag in the test/makefile.am

Comment: Are you defining `__GOOGLE_TEST__` when compiling the code in the SRC directory, or only when compiling the tests?

Comment: @Antonio Pérez : only when compiling the tests.

Comment: Then that's the reason :)

Comment: @Antonio Pérez: if I define in source code make file then the functionality wont work for them :-)

Comment: Then don't define it in source code but as a compilation option, i.e. `-D__GOOGLE_TEST__`, only when compiling tests. Anyway, conditional compilation for testing is usually a sign that you should factor out the code you don't want to run in the tests to a different class and then inject the dependency so that you can mock it up in the tests.

Comment: @Antonio Pérez: Source code and test code wont be modified everytime the code is fetched for testing to include the "-D Flag". Also i mentioned that I don't want to define in "source code make file" Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont rely on the compilation flags, without affecting the production code use the GMOCK methods to get rid off the while (1) loop , the code can go like below:

**TESTCODE:**

```
class test_common : public ::testing::Test {
};
TEST_F(test_common, create_common) {
    Common commonObj();
    ON_CALL(mock_if, GetBool())
      .WillByDefault(Return(true));
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_if, GetBool())
      .Times(AtLeast(1))
      .WillOnce(Return(true))
      .WillOnce(Return(false));
    commonObj. ProcessData ();
}
```

**ABSTRACT CODE:**

```
class AbstractIf {
 public:
  AbstractIf (void) = default;
  virtual ~AbstractIf (void) = default;
  virtual bool GetBool() = 0;
};
```

**MOCK CODE:**

```
class MockIf : public AbstractIf {
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(GetBool,bool());
};
```

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
class Common: public Thread {
 public:
  friend class test_common;
  Common {
  }
  ~Common () {
  }
  virtual void ThreadMain();
 protected:
  virtual void ProcessData(void);
  AbstractIf *prov_fl_if_;
};
void Common::ProcessData(void) {
  while (prov_fl_if_->GetBool())  { }
}
```

By this way we can skip the part of the code we want without affecting the production code

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a `#define` value from one compilation unit affect the compilation of another, previously compiled units. Given the list of things you have stipulated you don't want to do, you will have to use some form of runtime shenanigans.

You could make ProcessData take an argument that determines whether the loop should iterate:

```
void ProcessData(bool once=false);

void Common::ProcessData(bool once) {
    do {
    // ... your loop code
    } while (!once);
}
```

Or you could use a global variable that is defined in the module with your `main()` in it, lets call it `main.cpp`.

Production `main.cpp`:

```
const bool g_isDebugMode = false;
```

Unit test `main.cpp`:

```
const bool g_isDebugMode = true;
```

`main.h`

```
extern const bool g_isDebugMode;
```

now you can write runtime tests against this variable.

```
do {
// your code
} while (g_isDebugMode == false);
```

Comment: First Thanks for your try!! It is not possible if we call the ProcessData() via ThreadMain() (like passing bool variable to functions inside the functions in source code. It seems to be a overhead all the way in source code). In terms of GTest we don't have main.h etc.. to extern the global variable from different compilation units. @all any other ways using the Gmock etc..( I don't know..)